# ArcGIS python add in to call Python script for importing mdb data

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I'm trying to change from a.net toolbar to a Python toolbar in ArcGIS 10.2 and am having some difficulty.  I have some stand alone python script which I know works and does what I need to do but I can't work out how to get the add in button to call this script or how to incorporate the script in with the button add in script.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class ImportCSVFile(object):
    """Implementation for Import_CSV.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        script1 = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\AddIns\pythonAddin\Install\xxx"
        execfile(script1)
```

I've also tried using `os.startfile(xxxxx)` instead of `script1 = "xxxx"` and `execfile(script1)`.

I don't get an error but the button doesn't do anything.  Does anyone have any ideas of how to get this to work?

Comment: Could you just copy your script into the onClick() method instead of trying to call it from a location at all?  Another thought... It looks like your using "xxx" as a placeholder, but make sure it is "xxx.py"

Comment: Also, you could try "import os" at the top and then os.system("xxxx.py")

Comment: What happens when you replace `"C:\Users\xxx\Documents\AddIns\pythonAddin\Install\xxx"` with `r"C:\Users\xxx\Documents\AddIns\pythonAddin\Install\test.py"` and do something like `print "worked!"` as your total code in test.py?  Make sure that you have the Python window open to see any errors as you click the button.

Answer (score 2):

GeoJohn has the correct solution but here is the code sample

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import os

class Run_Script(object):
    """Implementation for addin_test_addin.Run_Script (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        os.system(r'C:\Data\test\importcsv.py')
```

As Geojohn suggested make sure you have a .py file extension and you will be best served to have Python interpret your file path as a [string literal](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). Do so by placing a r before the file path.