# Python Addin - Run script from button

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I'm developing a Python Addin for ArcMap.  This will consist of a button that will run another python script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import pythonaddins
import os

class ButtonClass1(object):
    """Implementation for Schaltflaeche_UID_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        os.system(r'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ToeB 10.2\Addins\Schaltflaeche_UID\Install\Insert_UID.py')
```

I've tried F_Kelner's answer posted in [ArcGIS python add in to call Python script for importing mdb data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160038/arcgis-python-add-in-to-call-python-script-for-importing-mdb-data), but I'm getting the following error, even though I have imported the os module:

> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.2\AssemblyCache{D9E1A7BE-8FE5-4EE5-9C9E-93C2B867EA3E}\Schaltflaeche_UID_addin.py", line 17, in onClick
> > >           workspace = os.path.dirname(workspace)
> > >       NameError: global name 'os' is not defined

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn about the site.  For ArcPy questions please always include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.  Also, error messages should always ne posted as text in preferemce to pictures so that they can be searched.  Your error here is that you appear to have missed including `import os` in your script.

Comment: edited.  as you can see, i'm importing os in the addin script.

Comment: You won´t need the `import arcpy` directive, as you already import `env` from `arcpy` on next line. Having two imports means first import the whole arcpy-namespace and afterwards load the env from arcpy (which has already been loaded by the previous directive).

Comment: Thanks, HimBromBeere, you are correct, but that isn't the problem...

Comment: Has your Python AddIn been re-made and re-installed since a possible addition of an `import os` line?

Comment: the import os line was part of the original addin installation.

Comment: i'm still not sure what the issue was, but i solved my problem using Michael Schneider's answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script

Comment: Would you be able to post the precise code that solved this for you as an answer rather than requiring a comment to be read that then points at an answer on another site to be read and interpreted, please?

Comment: I suspect the problem is the space in the folder name "ToeB 10.2" which results in a space in the file path.